# How to generate custom logs using rebot command?

Tags: xml, robotframework

I am executing set of test cases using robot framework as follows:

```
pybot -o output1.xml -l log1.html -r report1.html  testsuite.robot
```

this will create the output xml file along with report and log files respectively in my directory.

Now, consider there are 10 test cases in the above suite and out of which 8 are passed and 2 are failed. I will rerun these test cases using following command:

```
pybot --rerunfailed  -o output2.xml -l log2.html -r report2.html  testsuite.robot
```

I will get two xmls and then I wanted to merge them and get the final xml file as output1.xml along with new log and report files using following command:

```
rebot --merge output1.xml output2.xml
```

My concern is, here we are getting `log.html` and `report.html`. But, instead of these default files, can i get my customized logs with whatever name I give?

Like below

```
rebot --merge output1.xml output2.xml -l Final_Log.html -r Final_Report.html
```

How can I get logs with customized name after merging the two xml files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got re-worked on the question. Thanks To Goralight for sparking me idea of getting customized xml,log and report files.

Lets begin.

`pybot -o output1.xml -l log1.html -r report1.html  testsuite.robot`

```
pybot --rerunfailed  -o output2.xml -l log2.html -r report2.html  testsuite.robot
```

After this I got to merge these two xml files. I need new xml file, log file and report file respectively. So, with help of Gorlight's result and my further research i got following solution by which i am quite convinced.

```
rebot --merge --output Final_output.xml -l Final_log.html -r  final_report.xml output1.xml output2.xml
```

This gave me following three files

> Final_output.xml, Final_log.html and final_report.xml

At Last this is what I wanted. No This I integrated with my Jenkins report generator and populated the final pass/fail result.

Thanks a Lot Goralight for help.

Comment: Though in my case it worked great within my Jenkins job but a bit differently: 'ipyrebot --rerunmerge --output F
_output.xml -l F_log.html -r F_report.xml output-1.xml output-2.xml'

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the `--merge`.

If you want to join two logs together, use this command.

```
rebot -N TwoCombinedTests --outputdir C:/Path/Where/You/Want/To/Save Test1.xml Test2.xml
```

This will combine 2 test xmls for you with the names `Test1` and `Test2`. In the path you gave with the `--outputdir` option and with the final name of `TwoCombinedTests` thanks to the `-N` command.

Note; of course you will have to be in the current directoy where these xml file are being stored in. If using the terminal just a simple `cd /path/to/xmls` will suffice.

Edit - In my case, when I run my tests (around 6 robot files) It would generate 6 of each file (report, log output) each having their own custom name (name of the test along with the build/sprint number.) I would then throw these names into a sprint and merge them all. Here is the example of the script I use for you to understand what rebot is meant for (not over thinking what is it)

```
# command to combine all the reports into one large report.
os.system('rebot -N AllCombinedTests-' + SprintSlash + '-' + Build + ' '
          '--outputdir C:/AutomationLogs/' + Product + '/Combined/'
          + Version + Sprint + Build + " " + TotalXml)
```

Where TotalXml is a string list of all XMLs found.

Edit2:

```
rebot --merge --name ExampleName original.xml merged.xml
```

This rebot command will combine two output xmls for you (original.xml and merged.xml) with the name ExampleName

From here you will have a big "output xml" which you can then just run rebot again to generate a report/log from it

```
rebot -N NameThatYouWant ExampleName.xml
```

This will use the XML you just generated along with the name "NameThatYouWant "

Any questions please ask away.

Comment: Thanks @Goralight. So, you mean to say, -N command will merge the two xml files and give you the new xml with mentioned name. But, what about the log file ? will it be log.html or TowcombinedTests.html. Please confirm.

Comment: The `-N` command will name the child of the two combined output.xml's. So you give it the XMLs test1 and test2. It will read through these, merge them into the final report/log files as `TwoCombinedTests.html` in the dir you gave

Comment: If you want to combine the two outputs into another xml file, that seems redundant to me if you then want to generate a combined log for it. Youre better of just skipping the middle man and generating a combined log/report from the list of xmls you want. I'll check for you now though.

Comment: @GenCoder Please see my Edit2 on the answer :)

Comment: Thanks For the help. It helped me a lot for execution. thanks once again.

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help :)